# How to open menu - Blazor

Tags: html, asp.net-core, blazor

I have this code:

```html
<header>
    <div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
        <nav>
    </div>
</header>

<!-- Menu -->
<nav id="menu">
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want click in Menu and open the menu...but only link change for https://localhost:7084/#menu but page still in same posicion. Nothing happen.

[image]

I'm using Blazor Component.

Comment: Your question needs more explanation!

Comment: @user13256346 try now

Comment: Do you mean create a Navbar menu, did you try to check bootstarp? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/

Comment: Did that help you?

Comment: @user13256346 No, I just need to understand why i click on the sandwich and not open the menu, but appear the #menu the link

Comment: `<a href="#menu">Menu</a>` is a link tag. Clicking on it will redirect to what is inside `href`. Here, it redirects on the current page, focusing the page view (regarding scrollbar), on the HTML element having `id="menu"`.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine but why my menu dont opened?

Comment: You must have some css included, because from the code you only gave, I don't see anything to open. You probably also have some Javascript handling the menu opening.

Answer (score 0):

You said,

> I want click in Menu and open the menu...but only link change for
> https://localhost:7084/#menu but page still in same posicion. Nothing
> happen.

You have only posted the HTML code for your menu. There should be some CSS code for the designing of the menu and some JavaScript code to make the menu work.

if you don't have the JS code along with your HTML code then your menu will not work.

Generally, when you click on the menu icon then some JS function/ code gets executed and shows you the menu items.

You could refer to [How TO - Mobile Navigation Menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp) to get a detailed working code example for the menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #wrapper {
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.45s ease;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.45s ease;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.45s ease;
        transition: opacity 0.45s ease;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    #menu {
        -moz-transform: translateX(22em);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(22em);
        -ms-transform: translateX(22em);
        transform: translateX(22em);
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.45s ease, visibility 0.45s;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.45s ease, visibility 0.45s;
        -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.45s ease, visibility 0.45s;
        transition: transform 0.45s ease, visibility 0.45s;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 22em;
        max-width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        background: #585858;
        color: #ffffff;
        cursor: default;
        visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 10002;
    }
   

     #menu > .inner {
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.45s ease;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.45s ease;
            -ms-transition: opacity 0.45s ease;
            transition: opacity 0.45s ease;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 2.75em;
            opacity: 0;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

   

 #menu > .inner > ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

        

    #menu > .inner > ul > li {
                padding: 0;
                border-top: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
            }

            

    #menu > .inner > ul > li a {
                    display: block;
                    padding: 1em 0;
                    line-height: 1.5;
                    border: 0;
                    color: inherit;
                }

            

#menu > .inner > ul > li:first-child {
                border-top: 0;
                margin-top: -1em;
            }

   

     #menu > .close {
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.45s ease, -moz-transform 0.45s ease;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.45s ease, -webkit-transform 0.45s ease;
            -ms-transition: opacity 0.45s ease, -ms-transform 0.45s ease;
            transition: opacity 0.45s ease, transform 0.45s ease;
            -moz-transform: scale(0.25) rotate(180deg);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.25) rotate(180deg);
            -ms-transform: scale(0.25) rotate(180deg);
            transform: scale(0.25) rotate(180deg);
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 2em;
            left: -6em;
            width: 6em;
            text-indent: 6em;
            height: 3em;
            border: 0;
            font-size: 1em;
            opacity: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

   

 #menu > .close:before, #menu > .close:after {
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
        transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 2em 2em;
    }

    

#menu > .close:before {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cstyle%3Eline %7B stroke-width: 8px%3B stroke: %230093ca%3B %7D%3C/style%3E%3Cline x1='15' y1='15' x2='85' y2='85' /%3E%3Cline x1='85' y1='15' x2='15' y2='85' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
        opacity: 0;
    }

    

    #menu > .close:after {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cstyle%3Eline %7B stroke-width: 8px%3B stroke: %23585858%3B %7D%3C/style%3E%3Cline x1='15' y1='15' x2='85' y2='85' /%3E%3Cline x1='85' y1='15' x2='15' y2='85' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
            opacity: 1;
        }

    

    #menu > .close:hover:before {
            opacity: 1;
        }

    

    #menu > .close:hover:after {
            opacity: 0;
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).